# Visual studio 2010 - C++ Fatal Error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++

Consider the `Interface` class:

```
class Interface
{
public:

    virtual ~Interface(){}

    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
    virtual void someMethod2(){}
};
```

Where `someMethod` is pure virtual and `someMethod2` is virtual
Then two derived classes `Derived`

```
class Derived : public Interface
{
public:
    Derived(){ cout << "derived constructor";}

    ~Derived(){ cout << "derived destructor";}

    virtual void someMethod() override { cout << "derived someMethod";}
    virtual void someMethod2() { cout << "derived someMethod2";}

};
```

and  `DerivedB`:

```
class DerivedB : public Interface
{
public:
    DerivedB(){ cout << "derivedB constructor";}

    ~DerivedB(){ cout << "derivedB destructor";}

    virtual void someMethod() override { cout << "derivedB someMethod";}
};
```

Which implements just the pure virtual method.
In the `main` I'm doing the following:

```
vector<Interface *> myVector(4);


for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(i%2 == 0){
        myVector[i] = new Derived();
    }else{
        myVector[i] = new DerivedB();
    }
}
```

When I try to build I get the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DerivedB::DerivedB(void)" (??0DerivedB@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What is wrong?

Comment: and where your implementation of `DerivedB::DerivedB` ? implement it and error is disappear

Comment: I already implemented the `DerivedB` constructor in the .cpp. I updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement also other methods for derived classes you declare, namely `Derived::~Derived(void)`, `Derived::someMethod(void)`, `Derived::someMethod2(void)`, `DerivedB::~DerivedB(void)` and `DerivedB::someMethod(void)`.

See this post: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) and [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I'm sorry. I had to remove manually the .o files. Now it works.